# Where I can see IP of my application?

Tags: appharbor

I've added custom hostname for my application and now I need get IP address of the application to set it in CNAME. Where I can take it? 
Thanks.

Comment: why you need a IP to set CNAME? Do you mean A record

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868881/how-do-i-allow-my-users-to-use-custom-domains-on-appharbor here suggested use A or better CNAME, When I added hostanme to may app I can't see instructions how to update them for hostanme provider. Where I can see it?

Answer (score 1):

This was [answered on AppHarbor support](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/2689-add-new-hostname-for-application), the relevant IP address is displayed in the AppHarbor interface.